# Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Post' not found

Tags: php, exception, laravel-5

I am new to laravel and I got exception descripted in title. I know that I need to "use App\Model_Name;". Please Help! 
This is Model Class

```
<?php

 namespace App;

 use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

 class Product extends Model
 {

 }
```

This is Controller class

```
<?php

  namespace App\Http\Controllers;

  use Illuminate\Http\Request;
  use App\Product;

  class ProductsController extends Controller
 {
/**
 * Display a listing of the resource.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function index()
{
    return Post::all();
    return view('products.index');
}

/**
 * Show the form for creating a new resource.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function create()
{
    //
}

/**
 * Store a newly created resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function store(Request $request)
{
    //
}

/**
 * Display the specified resource.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function show($id)
{
    //
}

/**
 * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function edit($id)
{
    //
}

/**
 * Update the specified resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    //
}

/**
 * Remove the specified resource from storage.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function destroy($id)
{
    //
}
```

}

Comment: I think you mean `Product::all()` not `Post:all()`

Comment: Thanks, man! It helped. In the example video author worked with Posts(blog) and i thought Post is the method, not the name

Answer (score 5):

**put**
`use App\Post;`

**just below**
`use Illuminate\Http\Request;`

*in your controller class*

Answer (score 1):

you should use PostController   and not ProductController

```
  <?php

    namespace App\Http\Controllers;

    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    use App\Product;

    class PostController extends Controller
   {
  /**
   * Display a listing of the resource.
   *
   * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
   */
  public function index()
  {
      return Post::all();
      return view('products.index');
  }
```

Comment: But ProductController is one I created for working with model. Is the name make difference?

Comment: If you want access  to a controllerAction for PostController  be sure you have a PostController .. otherwise  you get the error you show in question ..

Answer (score 1):

Change this
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Product;

into 
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Post;